# How to successfully compile a C# program

Tags: c#

I created a file test.cs and tried to create an instance of the Window class:

```
class Test {
    static void Main() {
        new System.Windows.Window();
    }
}
```

I tried to compile it on the command line:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe test.cs
```

It says, the type or namespace 'Window' does not exist in 'System.Windows'.

How would I be supposed to compile that file?

Comment: Are you referencing the right assemblies?

Comment: You need to add a reference to PresentationFramework.dll. A simpler test program would just use `System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, world");`

Comment: @user3284699 What Jon Skeet said.  P.S., those gigabytes of Visual Studio would have helped you with that :).

Comment: Here's instructions on how to use csc on the command line, but you'll have to gather together all your references and build them by hand to make it work. http://www.charlespetzold.com/key/CommandLine.html

Comment: Side note: using command line tools *require* reading manuals (like MSDN and inline help - "csc/?"). Based on your question you may not like such activity and installing one of smaller editions of VS (I.e. Express for Desktop) may be better solution.

Comment: I posted the command line I use. I tried to link with PresentationFramework.dll in multiple ways, but I didn't manage to.

Comment: If you are concerned about the cost, VS 2013+ has a Community Edition that is free.

Comment: @AWinkle I am concerned about the massive CPU and RAM usage, I know it from Android Studio. I really prefer using a text editor and the command line.

Comment: @user3284699 Chrome ends up using more CPU and RAM on my machine than Visual Studio 2015 CTP Ultimate.  I'd really think about getting rid of Chrome first

Comment: @user3284699 1.6ghz cpu and 1gb of ram are fairly low requirements. I currently have 5 instances of VS2013 open, using 2.1gb memory and 0% idle CPU, ~25% during build. The benefits of the full-fledged IDE are worth not being able to play Star Craft 2 on ultimate graphics while coding.

Comment: This is probably an assignment that requires OP to not use Visual Studio.

Comment: I has to be requirement because i have a 4.95 gig solution opened right now and it takes 215 meg RAM and firefox open with 1 SVN and 2 stackoverflow tabs use 225 meg RAM. So definitively lightweight compared to other sotware.

Comment: @FunctionR if that was the case we would not be making fun of him.  But he did actually state in an earlier comment (which he deleted) that he wants to learn with the command line because he did not want to install "the multiple gigabytes Visual Studio".

Comment: @MikeNakis That's in the question itself, though it may have been in a comment also.

Comment: Learning how to build applications from the command line is a useful skill; but Visual Studio really does do a lot of work for you and if you decide not to use it you will have to learn how to do “a lot of work” yourself. If something this simple stumps you, I do not have much confidence in your success.

Comment: @MikeNakis hehehe, that might be true. However, from experience, I find that people with homework come up with elaborate excuses.

Comment: @mason wh00ps, you are right!

Comment: @user3284699: I fail to see how I was rude at all. I told you the assembly you had to reference, and suggested a simpler approach to get started with building from the command line. In what possible way is that rude?

Comment: @user3284699: Additionally, as you said: "I posted the command line I use. I tried to link with PresentationFramework.dll in multiple ways, but I didn't manage to" - you should include in your question what you've tried, so we can help you work out what you were doing wrong, rather than starting from scratch, as it were.

Comment: @JonSkeet You know, a "simpler test program" could as well just use an empty Main function. I managed to build that. This was not my question though.

Comment: @user3284699: Yes, but it's a better indication of the compilation *working* properly if you build something that gives you some output. If your question was really about "How to I build code which references WPF from the command-line" you should have phrased it that way. As it was, it sounded like this was the very first thing you'd tried to compile, and you hadn't managed to compile *anything* yet. How you write a question - the context you give - is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get all of your references right:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationFramework.dll;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationCore.dll;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Xaml.dll;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\WindowsBase.dll Test.cs
```

Also, if you are going to show UI, you need to include the `STAThread` attribute on your main method.

```
class Test {
[System.STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        new System.Windows.Window();
    }
}
```